# Jenkins fails with github "git clone"

Tags: github, jenkins

When I do build in Jenkins, it fails with this error. Any idea?

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone git@github.com:test/test.git
ERROR: Cause: Error performing command: git clone --progress -o origin 

git@github.com:test/test.git /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace
Command "git clone --progress -o origin git@github.com:test/test.git 
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace" returned status code 128: Initialized empty Git 
repository in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace/.git/

No protocol specified

(ssh-askpass:801): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: I answer this a similar question, you can see the answer in the link below: <br> [jenkins & GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515039/jenkins-git-permission-denied-publickey/8143432#8143432) <br>
<br>
Thanks you, <br>
gustavo

Answer (score 23):

You need to copy your private ssh key into the `.ssh` folder beneath Jenkins.  Something like (on Ubuntu Lucid):
`/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh`

Comment: You'll need to chown the files you copy into /var/lib/jenkins. In addition, you may want to copy your .gitconfig file into /var/lib/jenkins

Comment: Better yet, don't put your private keys in other places than your own home directory. Create a new set of keys for jenkins, and give the jenkins public key to github.

Answer (score 15):

**Host key verification failed.** - make sure your SSH keys are setup properly.

http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/

After you are done with that,

```
ssh git@github.com
```

should give you a welcome message ( which also says no shell access ) from GitHub

Comment: even "git clone git@github.com:test/test.git" works when I do "sudo git clone git@github.com:test/test.git" it fails.

Comment: What user are you doing that as?  The jenkins user?

Comment: Why are you sudoing?  Sudo changes the user, and thus the keys used.  You probably should *not* be using sudo.

Comment: sudoing to root i believe. however, the jenkins build fails with the same error as sudoing.

Comment: @Sam that means that the keys to github works for your own user, but not for the user that jenkins is running under. You need to set that up too.

Comment: Try `sudo su jenkins -` and then make it work as the Jenkins user.  This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem, even though the ssh-keys were correctly set up.

The issue was that on the first connection attempt, the git-server needed to be added to the known hosts file

> /.ssh/known_hosts

. Git prompts you for this on first connect-attempt: ***Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?***, but Jenkins did not nor can it pass on the prompt, so it failed silently.

We solved it by walking to our ops-guy, bringing him a nice cup of espresso, and had him do a random git-checkout, where he answered ***yes*** to said prompt :) After that, checkouts through Jenkins worked as expected.

Found the clue here: http://www.ipsure.com/blog/2010/ssh-public-key-w-rsa-authentication-and-ssh-tunneling-part-1/

Comment: this was my problem too :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you still have **the Host key verification failed** problem I answered a similar problem with a step by step solution here :

[Jenkins & Github not using SSH Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060226/jenkins-github-not-using-ssh-key/13658305#13658305)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I ended up with simply using https instead of ssh to clone the repository from GitHub to Jenkins.

So instead of: `git@github.com:[user]/[repository].git` I used: `https://github.com/[user]/[repository].git` as the repository URL.