# jenkins complains host key verification failure although the key was generated

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, hudson, jenkins

```
Error:
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:....../.........git
    ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
    hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: git fetch -t git@github.com:....../......git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    Command "git fetch -t git@github.com:...../......git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128: Host key verification failed.
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

My comments:

1. I found that jenkins build fails when it executes

   ```
   git fetch -t git@github.com:...../......git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   ```
2. I then pasted the same command on the command line it executes it successfully, weird!
3. Executed the following to ensure the key works:

   ```
   ssh -T git@github.com
   Hi [username]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
   ```

   Suggested in http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/
4. I did try to copy the generated private ssh key into the .ssh folder beneath Jenkins

   ```
   cp -rf /root/.ssh /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh
   ```

   and also copied the .gitconfig file into /var/lib/jenkins

   Suggested in: [Jenkins fails with github "git clone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103684/jenkins-fails-with-github-git-clone)

Comment: It's referring to the host key, not your public/private key.

Comment: When you try it on the command line are you running as the same user that Jenkins is running under? You will need to add the host key as an allowed host for the Jenkins user.

Comment: To robert: Thanks, I will check this

Comment: To codemonkey: Yes from Jenkins web, I am logged in as myself to run the  configured build. But, I did a 'sudo' into the jenkins system to execute it at the command prompt. I will try the latter suggested and see if that resolves the issue. Many thanks.

Comment: Fixed: The .git was owned by root while the others were owned by jenkins. A work around would be : http://happy-coding.com/jenkins-github-and-host-key-verification-failed/

Comment: But I did not have any intense configuration to loose in the project. So deleted it and recreated another. And this time...........I just logged into the system and **** DID NOT SUDO **** to create the git config . Instead just executed git config user.email "emailid@abc.com" and git config user.name "User name" .The jenkins build had success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

But I did not have any intense configuration to loose in the project. So deleted it and recreated another. And this time...........I just logged into the system and **** DID NOT SUDO **** to create the git config . Instead just executed git config user.email "emailid@abc.com" and git config user.name "User name" .The jenkins build had success!

Alternate solution: The .git was owned by root while the others were owned by jenkins. A work around would be : happy-coding.com/…